# How to make an UIAlertView when application brought to foreground from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Currently I am showing a `UIAlertView` on `viewDidLoad`, however once it goes into the background and brought back up, it does not appear again. How do I resolve this issue? What delegates do I need and how do I go about doing that?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert!" message:@"This is an Alert!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel!" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [myAlert show];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

apple doc: [UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(yourMethod) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    // don't forget remove it
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)yourMethod
{
    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert!" message:@"This is an Alert!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel!" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [myAlert show];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show Alert only one time when app comes in Foreground or become active than you can write alert code in following method of Appdelegate.

```
applicationDidBecomeActive
```

Answer (score 0):

use `viewWillAppear` method to show alert, if you need to perform this action everytime view appears

Answer (score 0):

You can override `viewDidLoad` and subscribe to `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showAlert:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
    [self showAlert:nil];
}

- (void)showAlert:(NSNotification *)noti {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" message:@"This is a test" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AppDelegate.m has default delegates methods ,make use of it.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application{    
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{    
}
```